# Creating a separate date and time variable

Tags: r, variables, time

I am working with incident data. The dataset has one variable (IncidentDateTime) for the date and time of an incident (written as: "1/2/21 0:21") and the variable type is character (chr). Is there a way for me to create a new variable that only has the time for each incident rather than the date and time? My end goal is to re-write the data so that the times are in a 24 hour clock.

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

If the date is always separate by time with " ":

```
library(stringr)
df <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(df, " ",2))
colnames(df) <- c("Date", "Time")
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract only the existing Time data I have from the IncidentDateTime Variable?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is able to solve your problem

```
(dObj <-as.POSIXct('1/2/10 0:21',format='%m/%d/%y %M:%S')
[1] "2010-01-02 00:00:21 +04"
```

If you wish to extract each date part separately, functions below from lubridate package will help you.

```
minute(dObj)
second(dObj)
month(dObj)
```